# Why does it take a long time for the beacon to recognize the device when I run the app again?

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

Currently, I am developing a beacon recognition function using the altbeacon library.
I designed a specific activity to trigger an event when the device approaches the beacon using `didRangeBeaconsInRegion()` function.

When I run the app for the first time, it immediately recognizes the beacon and triggers an event. However, there is a delay of about 20 seconds when the app is turned off and on again, or when the activity is left and returned again.

If you check the log, the code below repeats once every 5 seconds. This code must appear 4 times to recognize the beacon. Is there a way to reduce this delay or recognize the beacon all at once?

```
ScanState says background mode for ScanJob is false
2021-10-11 17:20:32.623 I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
2021-10-11 17:20:32.624 I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
2021-10-11 17:20:32.624 I/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
2021-10-11 17:20:32.624 D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
2021-10-11 17:20:32.625 D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=6 scannerId=-1 mScannerId=0
```

I tried the code below to solve this problem, but it didn't solve the problem I asked.

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100); 
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0); 
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000); 
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(300000);
```

```
private static Long sampleExpirationMilliseconds=3000L;
beaconManager.setRssiFilterImplClass(RunningAverageRssiFilter.class);
RunningAverageRssiFilter.setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(sampleExpirationMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what is causing the problem here because you don't show your code that sets up scanning, along with the context of when you set up scanning (on a new Activity launching, from an Android Application class, from an Android Service).

The most likely cause of the problem is in the way your app starts/stops scanning and how that interacts with the Android app lifecycle.

A few tips:

1. Try the [Java reference application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) to confirm you no longer see the problem.  Then try to copy its code that sets up scanning to see if that fixes your issue.
2. If possible, start scanning exactly once and don't stop scanning.  Let the library throttle scans when your app is in the background so it does not use excess battery.
3. Accept the default settings (scan periods, expiration milliseconds, etc.) unless you really know what you are doing.
4. Use the "autobind" APIs in library version 2.19+ to start monitoring or ranging like this:  `beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(...)` and do not call `bind(...)` or `unbind(...)` directly.  Calling bind and unbind is a common cause of programming errors.